# rich:listshuttle - targetValue is null in bean class

Tags: jsf, richfaces

In my screen am using ListShuttle, when I move value form source to target Its happening only in screen, in bean am getting targetValue as null. I am using List of String as SourceValue. Some scenario its working fine. Some scenarios its not working

I could not find where I did mistake. Please help me. Thanks in advance

this is my xhtml code:

```
<h:panelGrid columns="1">
<style type="text/css"> .lishShuttle td{vertical-align:top;}</style>
<rich:listShuttle id="rptColumn" styleClass="lishShuttle" onmouseover="this.style.cursor='pointer'" sourceValue="#{dynamicBean.selectedData.avlblRptClmn}" targetValue="#{dynamicBean.selectedData.selectedRptClmn}" 
listsHeight="150" sourceListWidth="180" targetListWidth="180"   var="items" showButtonLabels="false"  valueChangeListener = "#{reportViewerBean.listShuttleListener}">
<rich:column>
<h:outputText value="#{items}"></h:outputText>
</rich:column>
<a4j:support event="onorderchanged" reRender="rptColumn" status="waitStatus" ajaxSingle="true" limitToList="true"/>
<a4j:support event="onlistchanged" reRender="rptColumn" status="waitStatus" ajaxSingle="true" limitToList="true"/>

</rich:listShuttle>
</h:panelGrid>
```

bean method :

```
public void listShuttleListener(ValueChangeEvent event){
    getLogger().debug("Inside listShuttleListener(ValueChangeEvent event)");
    HtmlListShuttle listShuttle = (HtmlListShuttle)event.getComponent();
    getLogger().debug(((List<String>)listShuttle.getTargetValue()).toString());
    getLogger().debug(((List<String>)listShuttle.getSourceValue()).toString());
    avlblRptClmn = (List<String>)listShuttle.getSourceValue();
    selectedRptClmn = (List<String>)listShuttle.getTargetValue();
    getLogger().debug("End listShuttleListener(ValueChangeEvent event)");
}
```

if SourceValue row is less than 17 its working fine in both Tomcat and Websphere, if its is more than 17, in websphere its not working, listShuttleListener method not called. I am struggling with this more than 3 days, some one pls help me.

Comment: am using richfaces-api-3.3.3.Final.jar

Comment: Its not the problem of 17 elements. Its because, any of the source String has more than one blank space in between then list shuttle ,selectOneMenu and Pick list all wont work in Web sphere.

Answer (score 0):

Its not the problem of 17 elements. Its because, any of the source String has more than one blank space in between then list shuttle ,selectOneMenu and Pick list all wont work in Web sphere.